# How do I dynamically populate an HTML form with data from an MySQL database?

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, forms, express

I am trying to make a form, with which I will be inserting multiple rows into a database table with fields: date, ticker, shares. In the form, I want to have inputs already made for tickers that exist from the prior time the form was used. (eg. if 2/01/2022 has tickers 'MSFT', 'TSLA', 'FB': then an input for each of those is made and they are labeled with the ticker). I believe I can get that with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT ticker
FROM sharesowned
WHERE date=(
SELECT MAX(date) FROM sharesowned WHERE shares <> 0
```

With that list of tickers, I want to make an HTML form as follows:

```
<form action="shares-on-date" method="POST">
  <label for="date">Date:</label><br>
  <input type="date" id="date" name="date"><br>

  <!--- hoping to pull "array" of tickers from a sql query somehow and use that to add 'i' inputs as follows: --->
  <label for="ticker[i]">ticker[i]:</label><br>
  <input type="number" step="0.0000000001" id="ticker[i]" name="shares"><br>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**My question essentially is: how do I get this query data and create 'i' number of inputs (one for each ticker) with the respective ticker as the label text. I am unsure of how I am supposed to even perform a MySQL query in HTML.**

The post method that the form is calling on action is as follows:

```
app.post('/shares-on-date', function(req, res, next) {
  var date = req.body.date;
  var tickers = req.body.tickers;
  var shares = req.body.shares;
 
  for(let i = 0; i < shares.length; i++) {
    var sql = `INSERT INTO sharesowned (date, ticker, shares) VALUES ("${date}", "${tickers[i]}", "${shares[i]}") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE shares="${shares[i]}"`;
    db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('record inserted');
      req.flash('success', 'Data added successfully!');
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  }
});
```

So along with needing the ticker query data within the HTML, I will also need it in the javascript post function in order to write the correct SQL query.

I will also need to add functionality to add a new ticker or remove them, but I haven't researched that yet and feel I might be able to do that myself later.

Thanks for any help or direction you guys can give me.

Comment: You can either use a templating engine like [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) to statically serve the page with the data, or you [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) to hit the post route and return the values

Comment: @about14sheep are you referring to the express.static() function? From what I can tell this is how you can access files in HTML. How do I use this to access results from an SQL query?

Comment: you use a templating package like ejs to pass the values from the query into the html page